# Where are the Document Viewer config files?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, configuration

I don't seem to be able to locate the configuration files directory for Document Viewer (I use it as a PDF viewer) in Gnome; in particular, in Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to regain access to my documents' bookmarks after reinstalling the OS. Would appreciate some insight.

Comment: related, much more information: https://superuser.com/questions/346345/where-does-evince-store-its-per-document-state-position-etc

Comment: The files are stored in binary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use "Evince"

It is here

```
$HOME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/
```

all bookmarks in *.log
but this is data files